# Некорректное имя скачиваемого файла

Tags: javascript, c#, html, pdf

**Вводные условия таковы:** По нажатию на контрол открываем в новой вкладке браузера файл. Файл передаем в виде `Stream`. Вкладку (через клиент) открываем с помощью `window.open(fileUrl, "blank");` , где `fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);`, а в свою очередь `file` - данные типа `Blob` возвращаемые с сервера (тот самый `Stream`).

**Что имеем в итоге:** требуемый файл открывается в новой вкладке и все вроде бы ровно, но только до того момента как мы его пытаемся его скачать. В зависимости от браузера имя скачиваемого файла или "document.pdf" или "BLOB-xxx-...-xxx.pdf", а надо бы "Имя_файла.pdf".

Для ответа, выдаваемого сервером проставляется `Content-Disposition: "attachment"; filename="Имя_файла.pdf"`.

**Вопрос:** каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы скачиваемый документ имел корректное имя?

Comment: Я даже заголовка такого не вижу, только [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

Comment: Первое: `Content-Descrption` => `Content-Disposition`. Второе: имя файла должно быть в ASCII кодировке, либо в UTF-8, но нужно убедиться, что оно поддерживается нужным браузером.

Comment: @aepot , это опечатка в названии заголовка. А так, кодировка совпадает (UTF-8). Со стороны все выглядит как должно, но что-то идет не так.

Comment: `Content-Disposition: attachment;` где `attachment` - без кавычек. [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, часть моих проблем решилась, когда я изменил код получения URL новой вкладки.

Изначально было так:

```
const file = new Blob([data], { type: mimeType ? mimeType : undefined });
return window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

После изменений стало так:

```
const file = new File([data], filename, { type: mimeType ? mimeType : undefined });
return window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Теперь, при работе в Firefox все корректно сохраняется. Но пока совершенно не хочет решаться проблема с Google Chrome. В этом браузере по-прежнему при сохранении отображается идентификатор BLOB.